# How to make sure parseInt() function does not return unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parseint

The following is a method that converts millisecond to human-readable time. However I got a comment about it that says it might return unexpected result for some radix.

```js
function msToTime(duration, sign) {
  var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
    seconds = parseInt((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = parseInt((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = parseInt((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? " " + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return minutes + sign + seconds;
}

$("div").text(msToTime(1203400, ":"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div></div>
```

This is the comment I have received: *"The `parseInt()` function can return undesired and/or unexpected results if the radix is not supplied.Please make sure a radix is used on all `parseInt()` instances."*

I tried to add day, week, month, year and so on, but I am not sure if that's the right way. Also it is for a duration of music. So there won't be any case for longer than hours I think.

Any idea to make sure the result of the method is always correct?

Comment: Maybe you should consider that whoever made the comment is wrong, as your code indicate that `durration` is already an int.  If I can be a string, such as a hex number, then you code is broken in different ways

Comment: What the comment above is trying to say is: you actually want to `parseInt` your duration *before* you begin performing computations with it. In your example, things will break before that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) takes a second parameter called radix as its second parameter

> An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in
>   mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. Specify
>   10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans. Always
>   specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee
>   predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different
>   results when a radix is not specified.

Since you are dealing with decimal number system, pass the radix as 10 to solve such a problem

```
parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. So I should specify the radix for every parseInt I use in my function?

Comment: @DanJF that depends on your use case... I normally do specify them

Comment: @DanJF - All of this info about `parseInt()` is technically true, but it turns out `parseInt()` is not even needed in the OP's function because they are passing in a number, not a string.  And, even if they passed in a string, you would have to do `parseInt(duration, 10)`, not `parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100, 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

Radix is the second parameter parseInt() takes, It's a number (from 2 to 36) that represents the numeral system to be used. You should use 10, as this represents the decimal numeral system.

```
var milliseconds = (parseInt(duration) % 1000) / 100, 10)
```

If no radix is passed the following will be used:

> If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal).
>
> If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is
>   deprecated
>
> If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
>   (decimal)

If you don't allways want to specify it, create a function like this:

```
function parseInt10(val){
    return parseInt(val,10);
}
```

Comment: In general, you want 10, unless you like experimenting with non-standard numeral systems.

Comment: @XMLilley would you consider binary, octal and hexadecimal non-standard?

Comment: @michael, you'll need to point out that your quote is for when no radix is passed e.g. if you pass a radix, `parseInt('0x10', 8)` will give `0`

Comment: Thanks @PaulS., I forgot.

Comment: @PaulS., Non-standard? For this OP? (Who didn't know what a radix was, and whose use case is clearly decimal?) For that user, anything but base-10 would be a very non-standard approach. (For that matter, binary, octal and hex-based computation may be very useful and essential tools, but they're utterly irrelevant to the vast majority of users, the vast majority of the time. What people need to learn first is how to do decimal.)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are offering your some advice about `parseInt()` which is technically correct, but irrelevant to your actual code because you do not even need to be using `parseInt()` in your function.

Since it appears you're already passing a number (not a string) into your function, you don't even need ANY `parseInt()` operations and can simplify it a lot like this:

```
function msToTime(duration, sign) {
  var milliseconds = (duration % 1000) / 100,
    seconds = (duration / 1000) % 60,
    minutes = (duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60,
    hours = (duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? " " + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return minutes + sign + seconds;
}
```

If you wanted your function to accept either a number or a string passed in for the duration, you could support that like this:

```
function msToTime(t, sign) {
  var duration = +t;
  var milliseconds = (duration % 1000) / 100,
    seconds = (duration / 1000) % 60,
    minutes = (duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60,
    hours = (duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? " " + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return minutes + sign + seconds;
}
```

---

And, if you did use `parseInt()`, you would convert duration to a number:

```
var d = parseInt(duration, 10);
```

And, then use that value in your calculations.  As your code has it now, you are calling `parseInt()` on the results of a mathematical calculation which means you're calling `parseInt` on a number which doesn't do anything.